# Reverse through array not working

Tags: arrays

This might seem basic, but I'm trying to loop through an array from the top `n` items down.
`submissionId` is the basically the length of the array, but always +1 of the actual latest index.

```
function getLastNSubmissions(uint256 n) public view returns (string[6][] memory) {
    require(submissionId > 0, "There are no submissions yet.");

    string[6][] memory returnSubmissions = new string[6][](n);
    
    uint stop = 0;
    
    // Make sure stop isn't negative
    if ((submissionId-n) >= 0) stop = submissionId-n;

    uint pos = 0;
    for (uint i=(submissionId-1); i >= stop; i-=1) {
        if (i < 0) break;
        Submission storage s = submissions[i];

        returnSubmissions[pos][0] = // assign something
        returnSubmissions[pos][1] = // assign something
        returnSubmissions[pos][2] = // assign something
        returnSubmissions[pos][3] = // assign something
        returnSubmissions[pos][4] = // assign something
        returnSubmissions[pos][5] = // assign something

        pos += 1;
    }
    return returnSubmissions;
}
```

But for some reason, this function errors when `n` is <= `submissionId`. This function only works, when `n` is lower than `submissionId`.

Expected result: If `n` is greater than `submissionId`, return all items available. Otherwise, return the last `n` items.

Answer (score 1):

Because your variables are uint and when you try to substract n from submissionId you get negative value but both of your variables are unsigned integers. Change your if statement to this:

```
 if(submissionId > n) stop = submissionId - n;
```

And i in for statement should be int not uint.

*This is also cheaper for the gas, with only one comparison instead of 1 calculation and 1 comparison.

Comment: I applied your changes, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Can you share your new code? I tried without a problem.